# How to get values from Visual Search form

Tags: jsp, servlets, request

I have the following Form Data passed from JSP page to servlet

```
qryStr[0][Value]:EMPNAME
qryStr[1][Search]:jack
qryStr[2][filter]:or
qryStr[3][Value]:EMPNO
```

In Servlet I am trying to receive form data by `request.getParameterValues("qryStr");`

However it always return null, what could be the reason? In JSP when page is submitted I am passing Visual Search `visualSearch.searchQuery.facets()`

Any help is highly appreciable.

Edit 1

Code snippet for passing data to servlet

```
function qrySearch(){
                $('#toolStr').datagrid('load',{
                        url: 'myservlet',
                        qryStr: visualSearch.searchBox.value(),
            });                        

        }
```

Comment: Show us your relevant code, or at least the actual query string that is sent to the server.

Comment: @JBNizet I have included in question code snippet where data is passed to servlet.

Comment: But we still have no idea of what the datagrid funtion does, and of the actual query string that is sent to the server. Open your chrome  developer tools window (or Firebug in firefox), go to the network tab, send the data, then copy the query string sent to the server and paste it in your question.

Comment: @JBNizet When the function is called datagrid is loaded and there is a call to servlet with data form. What I have pasted in my question the Form Data from Chrome's network tab.

Comment: Make sure to click "view source" in the Form data section, and to paste the result. I'd like to see the actual, exact query string, and not the chrome representation of it.

Comment: @JBNizet This is how it looks `qryStr%5B0%5D%Value%5D=EMPNAME&qryStr%5B1%5D%Search%5D=jack`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the query string you provided (which doesn't look correct, based on the chrome representation of it that you also posted), two different parameters are sent to the server. The first one is named `qryStr[0][Value]` and has the value `EMPNAME`, and the second one is named `qryStr[1][Search]` and has the value `jack`.

So, these are two completely different parameters: their name are different.

`request.getParameterValues("qryStr")` returns the values of the parameters named `qryStr`. So it would return EMPNAME and jack if the query string was

```
 qryStr=EMPNAME&qryStr=jack
```

i.e. if the parameter named `qryStr` was sent twice, with `EMPNAME` and `jack` as respective values.

To get the value of the first parameter in your servlet, you thus need to call `request.getParameter("qryStr[0][Value]")`. And to get the value of the second parameter, you need to call `request.getParameter("qryStr[1][Search]")`. The servlet API doesn't provide any method to help you parse those parameters and make something like a grid of parameters out of them. You'll have to do that by yourself.

Comment: I am trying to use Visual Search and per the documentation in order to parameter in array the following has to used `visualSearch.searchQuery.facets()` See option item # 4 [here](http://documentcloud.github.io/visualsearch/#usage)

Comment: Are there any method to know what are the form data which are passed to servlet? i.e. How can I know `qryStr[0][Value]`, `qryStr[1][Search]` are being passed?

Comment: request.getParameterNames() returns all the parameter names. request.getParameterMap() returns all the parameters. Read the javadoc.